# Toggle navigation for mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

My toggle navigation menu is working on a desktop view but when I run this demo on mobile view it does'nt works.

Please find the url : http://dev.genuusdemo.com/msite/index1.html

Please find the code of this :

script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gx-sidemenu').gxSideMenu({
            mode: isMobile.any() ? 'tiny' : 'normal', // normal | tiny
            interval: 300, // animations' interval
            direction: 'left', // left | right
            openOnHover: false, // true | false
            clickTrigger: true, // true | false
            followURLs: true, // true | false
            trigger: ".gx-menu-open.list", // class or id of trigger element
            startFrom: 60, // start pixel from corner on hover trigger
            startClosed: true, // menu opens on document load
            scrolling: true, // menu scrollable (iScroll plugin needed!)
            urlBase: '/sidemenu/', // document base URL
            backText: 'Prev | Back', // Back button text
            onOpen: function() { }, // Open callback
            onClose: function() { } // Close callback
        });


        $('pre.snippet').snippet("javascript", { style: 'ide-kdev' });
        $('pre.snippet-html').snippet("html", { style: 'ide-kdev' });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Lee : That is what i need help for

Comment: No, what I was getting at, is you have to be more concise in your question. What are you trying to do? What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens? What have you tried to fix it so far? - You cannot just ask us to 'fix it' without actually giving us any idea on what's wrong.

Comment: @Lee : this is nothing but mobile view site. When I trying to see this site on mobile the navigation is not working properly

Comment: As in what? The nav panel doesn't appear? the links don't work? The javascript isn't being fired? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: @lee: when I click on toggle navigation it doesn't appear

Comment: Are you able to use the console inspector with your phone? If have you have an iPhone, connect it via USB, and in Safari click Develop (If you've set Debug tools)